# How to animate a Single View one by one in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-animated

### Please have a look this image

[image: two muppets]

I have an issue in the animation of the circle.
The flow is:
When user will click on button 1, the circle will animate from real position to position 1,

When clicking button2, a circle will move from position 1 to position 2,

and

When clicking on button2, a circle will animate back on the real position.

I need 1 sec. time while animate and I want to set circle position at particular Y position.
mean the first position on Y=400, second position on Y= 100.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: please provide some code of what you already did.

Comment: Mr. @DragonBorn solved my problem, Thanks for your replay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [Animated](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated) library from react-native. Check out the library for more details on how to animate objects.

Meanwhile check the working example in [Snack.io](https://snack.expo.io/rJjzdKC04)

Here's the code.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Animated, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      posY: new Animated.Value(400)
    };
  }

  moveBall = (yPos) => {
    Animated.timing(this.state.posY, {
      toValue: yPos,
      duration: 1000
    }).start()
  };

  renderRectangle = () => {
    const animatedStyle = { top: this.state.posY };
    return (
      <Animated.View style={[styles.rectangle, animatedStyle]}>
      </Animated.View>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{ flex: 0.9, alignItems: 'center' }}>
          {this.renderRectangle()}
        </View>
        <View style={styles.buttonsContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity 
            style={styles.buttonStyle} 
            onPress={() => this.moveBall(250)}
          >
            <Text>Button 1</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity 
            style={styles.buttonStyle} 
            onPress={() => this.moveBall(100)}
          >
            <Text>Button 2</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.buttonStyle}
            onPress={() => this.moveBall(400)}
          >
            <Text>Button 3</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  rectangle: {
    backgroundColor: "#2c3e50",
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 50,
    position: 'absolute'
  },
  buttonsContainer: {
    flex: 0.1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    paddingLeft: 20,
    paddingRight: 20
  },
  buttonStyle: {
    padding: 5,
    height: 30,
    backgroundColor: 'limegreen'
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @DragonBorn for your help, it is very helpful and exact according to my requirement. I appreciate. Please keep in touch to work together, ping me on skyp(sagardhiman5_1)